# IIS 7 Copying files to server in differant domain

Tags: iis-7, domain, credentials

I have a need to copy uploaded files from an (Intranet) website folder into a network share on a server in a different domain. I have the credentials for a service account on domain B.

I am already doing this on a much larger scale by using a console app that runs as a user which has the domain B service account credentials stored in Credentials Manager.

I am trying to do the same thing by storing the service account credentials for the account being used by IIS 7. I can get the IIS process to use the account I want but it, apparently, refuses to allow the use of the stored service account credentials when trying to copy to domain B. I keep getting an error "Bad username or password".

Is it possible to get the IIS 7 worker process to authenticate to domain B using stored credentials from Credential Manager? Is there some other approach that I should be using?